# Developing Python modules - adding them to the Path

Tags: python

I am pretty new to Python so it might sound obvious but I haven't found this everywhere else

Say I have a application (module) in the directoy A/ then I start developing an application/module in another directory B/

So right now I have

```
source/
      |_A/
      |_B/
```

From B I want to use functions are classes defined in B. I might eventually pull them out and put them in a "misc" or "util" module.

In any case, what is the best way too add to the PYTHONPATH module B so A can see it? taking into account that I will be also making changes to B.

So far I came up with something like:

```
def setup_paths():
   import sys
   sys.path.append('../B')
```

when I want to develop something in A that uses B but this just does not feel right.

Comment: are you sure that this is not working?it does for me?or is it just the error in file name?you use _B

Comment: it is working. I am asking for the "best" or "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when you are developing a single application your directory structure will be similar to

```
src/
   |-myapp/
          |-pkg_a/
                 |-__init__.py
                 |-foo.py
          |-pkg_b/
                 |-__init__.py
                 |-bar.py
   |-myapp.py
```

This lets your whole project be reused as a package by others. In `myapp.py` you will typically have a short `main` function.

You can import other modules of your application easily. For example, in `pkg_b/bar.py` you might have

```
import myapp.pkg_a.foo
```

I think it's the preferred way of organising your imports.

You can do relative imports if you really want, they are described in [PEP-328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports).

```
import ..pkg_a.foo
```

but personally I think, they are a bit ugly and difficult to maintain (that's arguable, of course).

Of course, if one of your modules needs a module from *another* application it's a completely different story, since this application is an external dependency and you'll have to handle it.

Comment: Hi Krelagin, thanks for answering. But this is no what I was asking. I am taking that pkg_a and pkg_b are two different modules that will eventually be used by other application. Yet, I have to develop them concurrently and possible pkg_b will depend on functionality provided by pkg_a.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `imp` module

```
import imp
imp.load_source('module','../B/module.py')
```

Else use absolute path starting from root

```
def setup_paths():
   import sys
   sys.path.append('/path/to/B')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add proper folder to PYTHONPATH**

First, create the root directory for package that you create. Let's call it `project`.
Subdirs of `project` are your apps, that is `A` and `B`. Now you have to add the parent directory of `project` to `PYTHONPATH`.

**Refering modules inside the package.**

Let's say you have `other_app.py` in B, so in `A/app_name.py` you import it like this:

`from project.B.other_app import *`

Or if you want to have all symbols in `other_app` namespace import like this:

`from project.B import other_app`

**Nice way of creating launchers and dynamically change PYTHONPATH**

If you want to create universal app launchers for Python which work even when you move your package to other PC/dir you need some solution to dynamically add package parent directory to `PYTHONPATH`. Here is my solution to this case (for Linux, but you can also translate simple scripts to Windows if you google a bit :) )

In the same folder in which you created `project` create `pwd_to_pythonpath.sh`, short bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`
```

Then create launcher for your A and B, for example `A.sh` would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

source pwd_to_pythonpath.sh

python -m project.A.app_name
```

The `app_name` should be the same as module file name in `A` folder (`app_name.py` in this case)